Inserting svg icon inside element-ui el-tooltip
I'm using vue.js 2.6.10 and element-ui 2.15.1.
Is there a way to make an svg icon appear inside the el-tooltip's content attribute.
I want to add the following svg icon to the tooltip content:
<svg width="18" height="18" viewBox="0 0 142.916 142.916" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<path d="M32.901,114.799l-12.015,16.507c-2.375,3.265-1.656,7.835,1.608,10.21c1.301,0.945,2.807,1.4,4.295,1.4 c2.261,0,4.487-1.043,5.917-3.006l12.11-16.638c7.951,4.239,17.019,6.651,26.644,6.651c31.342,0,56.84-25.499,56.84-56.842 c0-15.979-6.636-30.427-17.283-40.764l15.074-20.709c2.375-3.265,1.655-7.834-1.607-10.21c-3.273-2.377-7.84-1.651-10.209,1.608 L99.313,23.562c-8.241-4.655-17.739-7.323-27.856-7.323c-31.343,0-56.842,25.499-56.842,56.841 C14.615,89.557,21.665,104.409,32.901,114.799z M113.682,73.08c0,23.284-18.94,42.226-42.226,42.226 c-6.407,0-12.461-1.477-17.905-4.039l48.729-66.951C109.331,51.864,113.682,61.964,113.682,73.08z M71.457,30.856 c6.901,0,13.403,1.698,19.159,4.646l-49.043,67.381c-7.623-7.643-12.344-18.181-12.344-29.801 C29.232,49.798,48.173,30.856,71.457,30.856z" fill="currentColor"/>
</svg>

Tried to pass it as a string but it failed to render it.
Is there another approach?

Welcome to StackOverflow, hope you will find new knowledge here. You can help us answering your question, by adding a minimal-reproducible-example StackOverflow Snippet with the [< >] button in the editor. It will help readers execute your code with one click. And help create answers with one click. Thank you.
